# Name Error: global name 'BaseFunction' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, spyder, pyopengl

I'm following a pygame tutorial (thenewboston) and I'm having some problem with pyOpenGL.
I'm using python 2.7 on anaconda-spyder3.3.4

Here's the code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *

import pygame

from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GLU import *

vertices = (
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1),
        )

edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7),

    )

def Draw_Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES) # delimit vertices.
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])

    glEnd()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)

    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL) 

    gluPerspective(45.0, display[0]/ display[1], 1, 50.0 )

    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5.0)

    glRotatef(20, 0, 0, 0)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()



        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        Draw_Cube()
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(10)
main()
```

I expected to get a 3D cube, instead it's showing this traceback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-8-72d57f8b0dbe>", line 1, in <module>
      glEnd()

 File "/home/cadu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGL  /latebind.py", line 61, in __call__
        return self.wrapperFunction( self.baseFunction, *args, **named )

 File "/home/cadu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/exceptional.py", line 45, in glEnd

return BaseFunction( )

NameError: global name 'BaseFunction' is not defined
```

So, I'm trying to search in Documentation but i haven't found anything about it. Could it be the pyOpenGL installation?

Comment: on my computer it doesn't work with `pygame.display.update()` - it says it can't update OPENGL display - but it works with `pygame.display.flip()`. Linux Mint 19.1 / Python 3.7 / PyGame 1.9.5

Comment: stop using Python 2 - see https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @furas, I was trying to change to python 3, but  got another problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839655/when-trying-to-install-pygame-on-spyder-python-3-x-is-downgraded-to-python-2-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to Python 3.5 it's working like a Charm.