# When trying to install pygame on Anaconda Python 3.x is downgraded to Python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, conda, pyopengl

I'm working with Anaconda Python 3. 
I'm trying to install pyOpenGL, Vpython and pygame.

Installing pyOpenGL and Vpython is fine using `conda install`.
When I try to install Pygame, using `conda install` it shows:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/kne pygame

#same for conda install pygame

...

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

.
.
.

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  backports.os-0.1.1-py37_0
  importlib_metadata-0.8-py37_0
  jeepney-0.4-py37_0
  jupyterlab_server-0.2.0-py37_0
  secretstorage-3.1.1-py37_0
  wurlitzer-1.0.2-py37_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

.
.
.

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
.
.
.
python                                   3.7.3-h0371630_0 --> 2.7.16-h9bab390_0
.
.
.
```

So if I decide to install pygame, I downgrade python3 to python 2.7 and I'm unable to use pyOpenGL. 
Is there a way to install pygame in this environment without downgrading python?

Comment: I use CPython but I have installed Anaconda3. In folder with `conda` I have also `pip` and using `pip install pygame` I can install `pygame` for `python 3.7` in Anaconda.

Comment: @furas I tried pip, but it was also asking to downgrade. The solution was creating a new conda environment and  installing OpenpyGL, than Vpython, pygame and later spyder. On python 3.5 . Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that there are not Pygame packages available for Python 3.7 from the channel you're trying to install it (i.e. `kne`). Since the last version available is for Python 3.5, you need to create a conda environment for that Python version and install Pygame on it.

Comment: I created a new Conda environment and it works fine now! Many Thanks!